# TypeError: col should be Column with apache spark

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have this method where I am gathering positive values

```
def pos_values(df, metrics):
    num_pos_values = df.where(df.ttu > 1).count()

    df.withColumn("loader_ttu_pos_value", num_pos_values)

    df.write.json(metrics)
```

However I get `TypeError: col should be Column` whenever I go to test it. I tried to cast it but that doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: withcolumn takes a column as second parameter where you set a costant value as df.where(df.ttu > 1).count(). df.withColumn("loader_ttu_pos_value", lit(num_pos_values)) may solve this error.

Comment: @ozlemg this might be the solution. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because `df.withColumn` expects a `Column` object as second argument, whereas you're giving `num_pos_values` which is an integer.

If you want to assign a literal value to a column (you'll have the same value for each row), you can use the `lit` function of `pyspark.sql.functions`.

Something like this works:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([("2022", "January"), ("2021", "December")], ["Year", "Month"])

df.show()
+----+--------+
|Year|   Month|
+----+--------+
|2022| January|
|2021|December|
+----+--------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

df.withColumn("testColumn", lit(5)).show()
+----+--------+----------+
|Year|   Month|testColumn|
+----+--------+----------+
|2022| January|         5|
|2021|December|         5|
+----+--------+----------+
```